# Spacing for first row in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, border

The submission guidelines for a conference depict following Word table:

[image: Original template]

So far, I got:

[image]

with following code:

```
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \centering
    \label{tab:lme-mean}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Table 1. A Sample Table}} \\
      \hline
                & Treatment 1 & Treatment 2 \\ 
      \hline
      Setting A & 125         & 95          \\ 
      \hline
      Setting B & 85          & 102         \\ 
      \hline
      Setting C & 98          & 85          \\ 
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test table with caption} 
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Question: How can I add more top and bottom space (i.e. adjust the padding) for the first row in my table? Also, increasing the width of the table a bit would be a plus.

Comment: You could add a "strut": `\vrule depth 2ex height 4ex width 0pt` after `\textbf{Table 1. A  Sample Table}`

Comment: For the width of the columns, you could instead use `p{.2\textwidth}` instead of `l` for the column-type to get fixed-length, larger columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with the package `makecell` and its macro `\thead{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx,}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\label{tab:lme-mean}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{Table 1. A Sample Table}} \\
    \hline
        & Treatment 1 & Treatment 2 \\
    \hline
Setting A & 125         & 95          \\
    \hline
Setting B & 85          & 102         \\
    \hline
Setting C & 98          & 85          \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test table with caption}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```