# Shortening the extra long vertical line after increasing the spacing for the first row in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-spacing

I'm designing a table. In order to increase the first row's spacing I've applied the solution at [Spacing for first row in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424977/spacing-for-first-row-in-a-table), i.e. add `\vrule depth 2ex height 4ex width 0pt` after the 1st row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\LTleft}{1pt}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{ll|c}
\textbf{Country} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{GDP p.c.}} & \textbf{Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c.}\vrule depth 2ex height 4ex width 0pt \\
Luxembourg  & 127,673 & 141,587 \\ 
Denmark     &  65,713 &  69,845 \\ 
China       &  12,970 &  21,291 \\
India       &  2,466  &   8,293 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption*{List of countries by GDP per capita \& Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c., 2022}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The solution worked fine but after I've added a vertical line next to the 2nd column, the vertical line extended over the first row's upper boundary.

[image]

How to shorten that line (or apply some other fix) so that the table looks decent as a whole?

**Optional / Relevant Question** I have a hard time specifying the thickness of the vertical line. How to set/increase its thickness, as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Change the `\vrule depth 2ex height 4ex width 0pt` to e.g. `\vrule depth 2ex height 2ex width 0pt`. If you want the extra vertical space above the `tabular` you can add `\vspace{2pt}`. For the thickness: `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{4pt}`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The solution works quite fine. If you post it as an answer, I'd select it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `\vrule depth 2ex height 4ex width 0pt` to e.g. `\vrule depth 2ex height 2ex width 0pt`. If you want the extra vertical space above the tabular you can add `\vspace{2pt}`. For the thickness: `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{4pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\LTleft}{1pt}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{ll|c}
\textbf{Country} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{GDP p.c.}} & \textbf{Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c.}\vrule depth 2ex height 2ex width 0pt \\
Luxembourg  & 127,673 & 141,587 \\ 
Denmark     &  65,713 &  69,845 \\ 
China       &  12,970 &  21,291 \\
India       &  2,466  &   8,293 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption*{List of countries by GDP per capita \& Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c., 2022}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularray` package, solution is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{caption}     
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, m] Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.3}] Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.3}]},
             rowsep  = 0.5pt,
             row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries, 
                        belowsep=4pt},  % set vertical distance between first and second row
             vline{3}= {2pt}    % set desired rule width, for default width write "{solid}" instead
             }
Country     & GDP p.c.  & Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c. \\
Luxembourg  & 127,673   & 141,587 \\
Denmark     &  65,713   &  69,845 \\
China       &  12,970   &  21,291 \\
India       &  2,466    &   8,293 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption*{List of countries by GDP per capita \& Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c., 2022}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, m] Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.3}] Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.3}]},
             rowsep  = 0.5pt,
             row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries, belowsep=4pt},
             vline{3}= {2pt} 
             }
Country     & GDP p.c.  & {Purchasing Power\\ Parity GDP p.c.}  \\
Luxembourg  & 127,673   & 141,587 \\
Denmark     &  65,713   &  69,845 \\
China       &  12,970   &  21,291 \\
India       &  2,466    &   8,293 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption*{List of countries by GDP per capita \& Purchasing Power Parity GDP p.c., 2022}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text box on page borders)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `tabularray` works quite fine, plus the `showframe` is sure to help diagnose the issues while designing tables. I'm sure to take a look at it as I design my next table.  I still had to select the earlier answer as it came earlier and worked the problem out.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen, you are welcome! Is there a specualč reason, that you have caption below table? Usual it is above table,  In this case you can employ `threeparttable` or `talltblr` and and limit caption width to table width. Many people like such table design..

Comment: yep there's a special reason for having the caption below the table: I'm writing down a scanned-PDF document in LaTeX and in that document, some of the tables are captioned in below :) Meanwhile, I have 2 other, ongoing problems with the tables, and I plan to post them as questions. 1st problem is about aligning the first row's (let's call it `header`) columns differently than the rest of the table, e.g. the `header` text will be center aligned the rest, left or right aligned. 2nd is about aligning the money units in a column by their decimal points.